# azure-storage-cpp cancel a parallel task

Tags: c++, azure, blob, storage

I'm currently implementing a C++ backend server using [azure-storage-cpp](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-cpp/blob/master/README.md) to download blob files locally. Azure Storage Cpp works on top of [cpprestsdk](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk) (casablanca), which provides parallel tasking.

The simple example from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-c-plus-plus-how-to-use-blobs) allows me to start a blob download. Fine. Now I'd like to know how can I cancel the download/task on demand?

I'm using [this method](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-cpp/classazure_1_1storage_1_1cloud__blob.html#a16d5ee00acd5bea06be49b1eff91da08) to download into a file.

This method returns a `pplx::task<void>`. So my guess was I could use this to properly stop the download.

But the documentation for pplx::task constructor says:

```
The version of the constructor that takes a cancellation token creates a task that can be canceled using the <c>cancellation_token_source</c> the token was obtained from. Tasks created without a cancellation token are not cancelable.
```

Window Azure Storage Cpp creates the task for us when calling *download_to_file_async*. So is there a way to cancel/stop a pplx:task created by azure storage cpp?

If not, I think I'm going to use the REST api with libcurl.